# Pebble Watchapp for Data Logging Example

Tags: android, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am new to Pebble and it's SDK.
I have installed the Data Logging Demo example app on my Android phone (Nexus 5 running Lollilop).
I have paired and connected that with my Pebble watch (Kickstarted Edition).

I want to install the corresponding watchapp on the pebble device. And i need help understanding how to build and install the watchapp. I don't see any apk or source for the watchapp part in the code i cloned from GitHub.

Any insights are greatly welcome. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Never mind folks. I found my answer. There is source available for an app called "Ocean Survey" that's written in C and i had to install the Pebbles SDK to build a native watch-app for the pebble device. After i build and install that app, then i was able to communicate with that watch-app from my Android phone app.

Thanks.